# Get current timestamp in firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing firestore rules function, which must return true, if certain value is between 0 and 1000 or bigger than current unix-timestamp. According to [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.timestamp), I'm trying to do the following:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{db}/documents {
    function check(i) {
      return i > 0 && (i < 1000 || i > (timestamp.epochMillis));
    }
// ...
```

However, rules editor gives me an error:

> timestamp is a package and cannot be used as variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you should be able to use `request.time` as follows (untested):

```
return i > 0 && (i < 1000 || i > request.time.toMillis());
```

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time), with `request.time` you get a non-null `rules.Timestamp`:

> When the request was received by the service.
>
> For Firestore write operations that include server-side timestamps,
>   this time will be equal to the server timestamp.

Comment: But how do I get current time?

Comment: Nice, thanks, I were looking through reference for a hour and didn't found it)